# Will zip -r command on remote server be cancelled if I exit terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, server, zip

I have done a lot of Googling, and cannot find an answer. 
I have made a "zip -r home" request on my server via my terminal.
The home directory is over 30GB. I need to leave the office at some point with my laptop.

I was assuming it should not matter, as the request was made on the Linux OS on the server, and my PC being online or offline should not matter at all. However, the terminal is showing me up to date status of the zipping process, which made me think twice before exiting.

Would the zip process be cancelled if I exit the terminal?
If not, how can I see the status again, once relogged.

Excuse me if this is a very basic question, I am a newbie and could not find a solution searching on Google.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will stop because your session no longer exists.

You can use [screen](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=screen%20attach%20detach%20command) utility.

you just run your command with:
`screen zip -r ...`

While its executing you press `Ctrl+A` followed by `D` (this is called detach)
In that moment you can disconnect from your session. It will continue zipping your folders. If it finishes before you come back the process will close as normal and your zip file will be complete.

you can check if there is something "screened" with `screen -list` and you can attach yourself back again with `screen -r <id>`.